# Why am I getting a segmentation fault with this code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, semaphore

I am getting a segmentation fault while running this code. I can't work out why this is happening - can anyone see a possible reason? (I have already got and initialized the semaphore's shared memory.)

My code:

```
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<sys/types.h>
   #include<sys/shm.h>
   #include<sys/ipc.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<sys/sem.h>

   union semun 
   {
   int val;
   struct semid_ds *buf;
   unsigned short *array;
   } arg;



  int main()
  {
  key_t semkey;
  int shmid,semid,nsem,sops;
  struct sembuf buf[1];

  char *ptrr,*shm,c,*s;

  semkey=ftok("/home/mawia/abc.c",'a');

  printf("entered into main of producer\n");
  if(semkey<0)
  {
   perror("ftok");
   exit(1);
  }

  shmid=shmget(semkey,30,0777);

  if(shmid<0)
  {
   printf("error");
   perror("shmget");
   exit(1);
  }

  shm=shmat(shmid,0,0);
  if(shm==(char *) -1)
  {
  perror("shm");
  exit(1);
  } 

  s=shm;
  semid=semget(semkey,1,0777);
 if(semid<0)
 {
  printf("error");
  perror("semget");
  exit(0);
 }

 ptrr=shm+1;
 *s='w';
 printf("going to check the value 0th semaphores\n");
 buf[0].sem_num=0;
 buf[0].sem_op=0;
  buf[0].sem_flg=0;
 buf[1].sem_num=0;
 buf[1].sem_op=1;
 buf[1].sem_flg=0;
  printf("entered the critical region\n");
 //printf("waiting to enter the buffer zone...");
 semop(semid,buf,2);

 printf("entered the critical region\v");
 if(*s!='r')
 {
  printf("\nPRODUCER IS PRODUCING\n\n\n");

  printf("ENTER DATA\n");

  while((c=getchar())!='\n')
  {
    *ptrr++=c;
  }
  *ptrr='\0';
  *s='r';
 } 

  else 
  printf("RESOURCE IS FULL:CAN'T PRODUCE");

 //printf("produced enough for  the consumer \nexiting from the buffer area now...");
 buf[0].sem_num=0;
 buf[0].sem_op=-1;
 buf[0].sem_flg=0;

 semop(semid,buf,1);

 ptrr=shm+1;

  if(!strcmp(ptrr,"exit"))
  {
  printf("exiting...");
  exit(0);
  }
  sleep(1);

 return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Try running with the debugger to find out *where* your code fails. Then edit this to a reasonable length and a more focused question.

Comment: Did you get a core dump file? Try opening that up with gdb.

Comment: @Mark Ingram: Sorry, I clobbered your edit. I tried to combine the two into the best of both worlds (and reverted your change of "while" to "whilst"! :P).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a quick glance (very quick), i would say that it MAY be caused by

```
struct sembuf buf[1];

/*some other code*/

buf[1].sem_num=0;
buf[1].sem_op=1;
buf[1].sem_flg=0;
```

You are accessing memory outside of the buffer. buf[1] reserves memory in the stack for only one struct sembuf, you are trying to use 2. In that case, you should use

```
 struct sembuf buf[2]
```

Comment: +1 Maybe you'll remove the buf[0]'s from your code block to show that the "bad" code is the one accessing bug[1].

Comment: really really thanks bro. that was the reason .really thanks for pointing out that.
thanks to all for reply.

Comment: get removed if buf[2] is defined.
   warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
   Reading symbols from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6...done.
   Loaded symbols for /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
   Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...done.
   Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
   Core was generated by `./producer'.
   Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
   [New process 6554]
   #0  0xb7fafd88 in strcmp () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
   why?

Comment: in the comment i have shown the out put of the core file after opening with gdb.even though the segmentation fault is removed using buf[2] but the core file shows that it is due to strcmp().when buf[1] is used and strcmp() is not used then there is no segmentation fault.
can you explain this contradicting behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Ah... there is obviously something very wrong when you declare

```
struct sembuf buf[1];
```

but a few lines later do

```
buf[1].sem_num=0;
buf[1].sem_op=1;
buf[1].sem_flg=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Array allocation too small.

This example is generally too long to be considered a good example; try to find a smaller (minimal is ideal) case which replicates the error, particularly one which depends on as few external libraries as possible.  Also, try running in the debugger and stepping through the code before asking.